# I cannot access the variable in the other script. (Module.exports don't work everywhere)

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, global-variables, module.exports

I have been having issues with **module.exports**.
I have 2 Scripts that use *Discord.js*, and i need to have a **SetTimeout()** variable that is common to both scripts to be able to use **ClearTimeout()** from each of them.
I tried to use:

```js
//first script
var foo = 20;
module.exports.foo = foo;
//Second Script
var exp = require('./firstscript');
console.log(exp.foo);
```

This was a test, to see if i was doing it the wrong way, with a simple variable instead of my SetTimeout().
The test worked fine when i ran *new scripts* with the **node** command 
but with **npm start** on my 2 original scripts it returned 'undefined' while having the same syntax.
In every script is already a **module.exports** for the *Discord.js* event class like 'Ready' for exemple. 
I'm running this bit of code outside the main **module.exports** at the top where the **const** are declared.
I wonder if this is causing my issue.

example:

```js
//the code i'm talking about is here.

module.exports = class ReadyEvent extends BaseEvent {
  constructor() {
    super('ready');
  }
  
  async run(client) {
```

Thanks for your help. 
Ask me for clarification if needed.

**EDIT:**
I looked up on the internet to see if it was an issue with the module.export that was already present on the script. And it was.

Apparently you cannot have several **module.export** in a script if each one of them doesn't specify a variable:

```js
//this doesn't work
module.exports.value = value;
module.exports = value2;
//this works
module.exports.value = value;
module.exportd.value2 = value2;
```

My problem was that the one already present was used by the 'discord.js compiler' to register every command so i couldn't  modify it without breaking the bot.

I decided to put my timer in a **new** script named GlobalVars and it worked Perfectly fine. 
I'm Satisfied that it works now.
 For me the issue is fixed but i would love to know if it is possible to export a variable WITH the discord.js module.exports syntax included.

Answer (score 0):

From your `Second Script` variable, its seems to be requiring a folder and not a file, and I don't think folders are allowed.

*Assuming you are requiring a script and not a folder:*

**First Mistake:** When requiring, inside the brackets you must have quotation marks (`""`) or (`''`).

If it is a folder, add a `/` next to `./firstscript` and assign it to the file you want to refer to.

```
var exp = require('./firstscript/THE_INTENDED_FILE');
```

...*If `firstscript` is a `json` file:*

```
var exp = require('./firstscript.json');
```

**Extracting Variables from file**

```
// Option 1:
console.log(exp.foo);
// Option 2:
const extract = exp.foo
console.log(extract);
```

Comment: actually I put the quotation mark, i just forgot it in the question. Also this isn't a folder issue because it works on the new scripts, and when I used console.log of the require const only, it showed that it was in fact an event.

Comment: the event from the module.export included with the discord.js event